# Entity Framework - Create Custom/Composite Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

A basic EF question which I'm not sure how to search for:

Using Entity Framework with a generated data-model, how do I create a composite/custom entity that essentially incorporates lookup data into the main entity, so I can reuse it in data-binding (and don't have to do the lookup each time on-the-fly)?

So, with this example, can I have a "SiteBU" Entity that has a lite of Sites that includes the "BuinessUnit1" value?

[image]

I'm aware that I can create a derived/inherited custom "SiteBU" Entity (see next image), but I'm not sure how to add the "BusinessUnit1" value to it:

[image]

I'm also aware that I can use custom LINQ entities, but for caching purposes I'd like to have my own "real" Entity rather than a generated/anonymous type - e.g.

```
using (var context = new ReportingEntities())
            {
                result = new Collection<Site>(context.Sites
                                                .Include("BusinessUnit") // Pointless because it's cast back to a Site?!
                                                .Where(s => !s.IsDeleted)
                                                .OrderBy(s => s.Site1).ThenBy(s => s.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnit1)
                                                .ToList());
            }
```

And this is the only manual (code-based) way I can see to construct the composite entity (here I manually created a "SiteBUEntity" that inherits from "Site" and has the extra BusinessUnit property in the constructor). Seems very laborious though.

```
using (var context = new ReportingEntities())
        {
            var siteBU = from s in context.Sites.Include("BusinessUnit")
                            where !s.IsDeleted
                            orderby s.Site1, s.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnit1
                            select new { Site = s, s.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnit1 };

            result = new Collection<SiteBUEntity>(siteBU.ToList().Select(s => new SiteBUEntity(s.Site, s.BusinessUnit1)).ToList());
        }
```

(Sorry if I have terminology wrong - please correct me).